# formula for square of absolute value of difference of two variables $|a-b|^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any formula for the expansion of $|a-b|^{2}$ ? Can I expand it in the same way as $(a-b)^{2}$?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have $|a-b|^2=(a-b)^2$. No difference! For $|a-b|=a-b$ if $a\ge b$, and $|a-b|=-(a-b)$ if $a\lt b$. Now recall that in general $(-x)^2=x^2$.

**Remark:** In our answer, we assumed that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, or variables that range over the reals. In the complex numbers, there is a notion of absolute value, usually called the **norm** of the complex number. In that setting, the answer becomes  more complicated.

Comment: what if b is of the form e^(ja) ?

Comment: @user13267: One can get an expression using the polar form. This takes us well beyond the question that was asked. If you are curious about detauls, do ask a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

Yes,
$$
|a-b|^2=(a-b)^2.
$$
The left hand side is just the number $x=|a-b|$ squared, while the right hand side is the number $y=(a-b)$ squared. But $x$ and $y$ differ at most by a sign, i.e. $x=y$ or $x=-y$ and hence if you square them, they are equal.