# Absolute Value of Complex Function to a Power

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, complex-numbers, normed-spaces, absolute-value

For complex valued function $x(n)$, is $|x(n)|^{2} = x(n)^{2}$?

This is briefly described in [formula for square of absolute value of difference of two variables |a−b|2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301991/formula-for-square-of-absolute-value-of-difference-of-two-variables-a-b2), but no further details are given

Comment: If my answer is not clear, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Not in general, take $x(n) \equiv \mathrm i$. Then $\lvert x(n) \rvert^2 = 1$, but $x(n)^2 = -1$.